# Deploying with Capistrano, rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano, activeadmin, rails-migrations

I can run `cap deploy` successful but when I try to run `cap deploy:migrate`, I getting the following error:

```
*** [err :: domain.com.br] rake aborted!
*** [err :: domain.com.br] PG::Error: ERROR:  Relation"posts"does not exist
*** [err :: domain.com.br] LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"posts"'::regclass
*** [err :: domain.com.br] ^
*** [err :: domain.com.br] :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
*** [err :: domain.com.br] FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
*** [err :: domain.com.br] ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
*** [err :: domain.com.br] WHERE a.attrelid = '"posts"'::regclass
*** [err :: domain.com.br] AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
*** [err :: domain.com.br] ORDER BY a.attnum
*** [err :: domain.com.br] 
*** [err :: domain.com.br] Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
*** [err :: domain.com.br] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    command finished in 8091ms
```

I have created the database already on the server running:

```
create database <databasename>;
```

**EDIT** 
Adding a migration sample:

```
class AddStatusTagsViewsToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :posts do |p|
      p.string :status, default: 'pending'
      p.string :tags
      p.integer :views
    end
  end
end
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you post the code of any migrations that include non-standard code? By standard I mean `create_table`, `rename_column`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I have the gem `activeadmin` listed on my Gemfile and this Gem adds a unique line on the `config/routes.rb` file.

The solution was comment the line added by the `activeadmin`, run the migrations, and then, uncomment it.

Comment: Same problem. Other reason. Same solution.
I got the same PG:Error on one of my models, when reopening an old project (new location, blank db).
Thought it had something to do with my ancestry gem.
This comment had me look into my routes.rb, where I solved my problem by momentarily uncommenting some stuff (I put there my self) while migrating my db.

Answer (score 0):

In one of previous migrations you should have `create_table :posts`, but it seems you have not. So you attempt to change non-existing table, that what Postgres is complains about.